# How can I define to libraries in the same CMakeLists.txt file and set include directories separately for each?

Tags: cmake

I currently define two libraries in the same CMakeLists.txt file, but one requires some additional headers. I would like to set the corresponding include paths only when that library is compiled. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Is it bad practice to define multiple libraries in the same CMakeLists.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_library(lib1 lib1.cpp)
target_include_directories(lib1 PRIVATE /path/to/dir)

add_library(lib2 lib2.cpp)
```

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html